# Determine arguments where two numpy arrays intersect in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, set

I have two arrays, say:

```
a, b = np.array([13., 14., 15., 32., 33.]), np.array([15., 16., 17., 33., 34., 47.])
```

I need to find the indices of all the elements in a that are not present in b.
In the above example the result would be:

```
[0, 1, 3]
```

Because a[0], a[1] and a[3] are 13., 14. and 32., which are not present in b. Notice that I don't care to know the actual values of 13., 14. and 32. (I could have used set(a).difference(set(b)), in that case). I am genuinely interested in the indices only.

If possible the answer should be "vectorized", i.e. not using a for loop.

Comment: is it just coincidence in this example, that they are both sorted arrays? (if they are sorted in the real version of your problem, you can abuse that property)

Comment: Sorry, I used sorted arrays to help reading. But I'm still interested to hear what you would do with sorted arrays :)

Comment: well, a custom algorithm might get an even better complexity by abusing the fact that they are sorted, (not really sure what complexity you would get in the end, but i assume better than whatever you do if you do not have that property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [np.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html):

```
>>> np.arange(a.shape[0])[~np.in1d(a,b)].tolist()
  [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy, use [`numpy.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) for calculating elements shared between `a` and `b`, then check which of those elements are not in `a` using [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and finally get their position in the array using [`numpy.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a, b = np.array([13., 14., 15., 32., 33.]), np.array([15., 16., 17., 33., 34., 47.])
>>> np.argwhere(np.in1d(a, np.intersect1d(a,b)) == False)
array([[0],
   [1],
   [3]])
```

If you prefer a list just add `.flatten` to convert the matrix to a vector and then apply `.tolist` to get the list:

```
>>> np.argwhere(np.in1d(a, np.intersect1d(a,b)) == False).flatten().tolist()
 [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straight forward if you use loops:

```
def difference_indices(a, b):

    # Set to put the unique indices in
    indices = []

    # So we know the index of the element of a that we're looking at
    a_index = 0

    for elem_a in a:

        found_in_b = False
        b_index = 0

        # Loop until we find a match. If we reach the end of b without a match, the current 
        # a index should go in the indices list
        while not found_in_b and b_index < len(b):
            if elem_a == b[b_index]: found_in_b = True
            b_index = b_index + 1

        if not found_in_b: indices.append(a_index)
        a_index = a_index + 1

    return indices
```

This should work with lists containing any one type, as long as they are the same type, and the `__eq__` function is defined for that type.

Doing this without loops would require a knowledge of python greater than mine! Hope this is useful for you.